# Options for hot deployment

Tags: c++

My requirement is to seamlessly hot deploy code update to a running service without losing the current status, including collection data. Is there any c++ framework out there I can use to develop such a solution?

Comment: You might want to look at Erlang, C++ doesn't support that well.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It's completely off-topic on Programmers.SE.... as it is here.

Comment: Basically, it is ahead the state of the art (at least for existing C++ code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should read some research papers on [**dynamic software updating**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating), e.g. on [Kitsune](http://kitsune-dsu.com/) (which you might use)

There is a major issue about updating the [*call stack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (and instances in local variables); read also about [*continuations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation); and you might have some special case (if your application is event loop driven like most GUI applications are, you probably want to update the code *outside* of event handlers).

You certainly should think of dynamic software update very early in your design. Perhaps some terminology and concepts from [**garbage collection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) & [**persistence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) & [**serialization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) techniques are relevant.

**Your requirement** (to seamlessly hot deploy code update to a running service without losing the current status) **is *very hard* and will need a *lot of work*** (probably years) and **is still a difficult & interesting research topic** (definitely it is a good PhD subject).

You might want to use your own [meta-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) techniques, that is generate most of the relevant C+++ support code by your own code generators.

If you already have a significant code base, you could consider customizing a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (e.g. to query the compiler's internal representations and generate some code from them) -but even that means a lot of work-

PS. Coding in something better than C++, like Erlang or Common Lisp, would make your goal less difficult.